# Google recaptcha validation using php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to validate serverside google recaptcha V2 using jquery and php.

Jquery code--

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("form[name='contactform']").validate({
            rules: {
                yname: {
                    required: true,
                    lettersonly: true
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                phone: {
                    required: true,
                    digits: true
                },
                subject: {
                    required: true,
                    lettersonly: true
                },
                message: {
                    required: true,
                    lettersonly: true
                },
            },
            messages: {
                yname:{
                    required: "Please enter your name",
                    lettersonly:"Please enter letters only."
                },
                email: 'Please enter a valid email address.',
                phone: 'Please enter a valid phone number',
                subject: {
                    required: 'Please enter the subject of your enquiry',
                    lettersonly: 'Please enter letters only'
                },
                message: {
                    required: 'Please enter a message',
                    lettersonly: 'Please enter letters only'
                },
            },
            errorLabelContainer: "#errorContainer",
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                //form.submit();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "recaptcha.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: $('#contactform').serialize(),
                    success: function (res) {
                        alert(res);
                        if(res == "error" ) {
                            alert('Please check captcha to proceed');
                            return false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            form.submit();
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        });
        jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element)
        {
            return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z ]+$/i.test(value);
        }, "Letters and spaces only please");
});
```

PHP

```
//The function post_captcha returns correct data
$res = post_captcha($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);

    if (!$res['success']) {
        // What happens when the CAPTCHA wasn't checked
        echo 'error';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'success';

    }
```

Now in the jquery code I get the alert prompt 'error' or 'success' but if I get 'error' then also the form is submitting. For some reason the if else condition is not working but I am getting the correct response from php code.

Any help  is highly appreciated.

Comment: Whats is your question?

Comment: @CesarBielich Even if the response is 'error', the form is still submitting.

Comment: What is `submitHandler` ?

Comment: Was event is triggering that executes your jquery? You have submitHandler but you must be doing something like a `validate`. Show the rest of your code.

Comment: @empiric submitHandler method is from jquery validate plugin. I am using jquery validate plugin to validate other fields and when the other fields are validated then I am checking the google recaptch using ajax

Comment: @CesarBielich Yes you are right. I am using jquery validate plugin.

Comment: are you certain the "error" is being returned? Also make sure there are no spaces at the ends. Maybe `res.trim()`?

Comment: @CesarBielich I have updated the post with full jquery code. Yes that line alert(res) is showing the response. Ok let me check the space.

Comment: What does your form look like? Post that too

Comment: @CesarBielich All good. I changed to if(res.trim() == "error") {...and it worked. There was a space :).

Comment: @CesarBielich Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help